# Smarty field value in If statement

Tags: smarty

I am trying to include a database field value in a Smarty if file exists statement like this.

```
{if file_exists('docs/owner_comments/{$property.id}.shtml')} 
{include file="{$incownercomments}/{$property.id}.shtml"}

{else} 

....

{/if}
```

However it does not work. The problem is with the first line. How can I include the field value in the {if file exists...} part?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `'` in first line into `"` and of course make sure path is valid

I've created test script:

**index.php**:

```
$smarty->assign('property', array('id' => 2));        
$smarty->display('testme.tpl');
```

**testme.tpl**

```
{$property.id}

{if file_exists("templates/testme{$property.id}.tpl")} 
{include file="templates/testme{$property.id}.tpl"}

{else} 

....

{/if}
```

**testme2.tpl**

```
testme2
```

Output is

> 2 testme2

as expected.  If I change in index.php line

```
$smarty->assign('property', array('id' => 2));
```

into

```
$smarty->assign('property', array('id' => 3));
```

and file testme2.tpl doesn't exists, I get output

> 3 ....

as expected